# Keycloak 18 - SQLException: Can not call getNString() when field's charset isn't UTF-8

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, keycloak, quarkus, mysql-connector

I have migrated keycloak from version 9.0.0 to 18.0.0 and when I try to invoke the endpoint **/auth/admin/realms/:realmName/users** an SQLException is thrown as below;

```
[2022-05-18 11:13:04.0466], DEBUG, org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper executor-thread-0 - could not initialize a collection batch: [org.keycloak.models.jpa.entities.UserEntity.attributes#<7b8ea28f-f3a1-4410-892c-d6055c857950, 1673bb70-a354-4bdc-a937-55f0ee12a15a, 5493996e-8725-4249-a68c-fffda9baada9, 88d7f5a5-93a2-4885-986e-31d36bc30a85>] [select attributes0_.USER_ID as user_id4_69_1_, attributes0_.ID as id1_69_1_, attributes0_.ID as id1_69_0_, attributes0_.NAME as name2_69_0_, attributes0_.USER_ID as user_id4_69_0_, attributes0_.VALUE as value3_69_0_ from USER_ATTRIBUTE attributes0_ where attributes0_.USER_ID in (?, ?, ?, ?)]: java.sql.SQLException: Can not call getNString() when field's charset isn't UTF-8
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getNString(ResultSetImpl.java:1060)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getNString(ResultSetImpl.java:1067)
    at io.agroal.pool.wrapper.ResultSetWrapper.getNString(ResultSetWrapper.java:1637)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.NVarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(NVarcharTypeDescriptor.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3214)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.hydrateEntityState(Loader.java:1811)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1784)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1624)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:748)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1047)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:998)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:967)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:327)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollectionBatch(Loader.java:2616)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.LegacyBatchingCollectionInitializerBuilder$LegacyBatchingCollectionInitializer.initialize(LegacyBatchingCollectionInitializerBuilder.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:705)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2203)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:595)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:591)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:387)
    at org.keycloak.models.jpa.UserAdapter.getAttributes(UserAdapter.java:254)
    at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.entities.CachedUser.lambda$new$1(CachedUser.java:66)
    at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.DefaultLazyLoader.get(DefaultLazyLoader.java:43)
    at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.entities.CachedUser.getAttributes(CachedUser.java:96)
    at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserAdapter.getFirstAttribute(UserAdapter.java:199)
    at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserAdapter.getUsername(UserAdapter.java:139)
    at org.keycloak.models.utils.ModelToRepresentation.toRepresentation(ModelToRepresentation.java:212)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.UsersResource.lambda$toRepresentation$2(UsersResource.java:459)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:442)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.StreamDecorator.forEach(StreamDecorator.java:153)
    at org.keycloak.utils.ClosingStream.forEach(ClosingStream.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:274)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$StreamBuilderImpl.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:411)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachOrdered(ReferencePipeline.java:502)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.StreamSerializer.serialize(StreamSerializer.java:71)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.StreamSerializer.serialize(StreamSerializer.java:15)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:400)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1514)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1007)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider.writeTo(ResteasyJackson2Provider.java:345)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.messagebody.AsyncBufferedMessageBodyWriter.asyncWriteTo(AsyncBufferedMessageBodyWriter.java:24)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ServerWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(ServerWriterInterceptorContext.java:87)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.asyncProceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:203)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.getStarted(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:166)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ServerWriterInterceptorContext.lambda$getStarted$0(ServerWriterInterceptorContext.java:73)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ServerWriterInterceptorContext.aroundWriteTo(ServerWriterInterceptorContext.java:93)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ServerWriterInterceptorContext.getStarted(ServerWriterInterceptorContext.java:73)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.lambda$writeNomapResponse$3(ServerResponseWriter.java:163)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ContainerResponseContextImpl.filter(ContainerResponseContextImpl.java:404)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.executeFilters(ServerResponseWriter.java:252)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:101)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:74)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:594)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:151)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.handle(VertxRequestHandler.java:82)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.handle(VertxRequestHandler.java:42)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1212)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:163)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextWrapper.next(RoutingContextWrapper.java:201)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.StaticResourcesRecorder$2.handle(StaticResourcesRecorder.java:67)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.StaticResourcesRecorder$2.handle(StaticResourcesRecorder.java:55)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1212)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:163)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextWrapper.next(RoutingContextWrapper.java:201)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$5.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:380)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$5.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:358)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1212)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:163)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextWrapper.next(RoutingContextWrapper.java:201)
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.integration.web.QuarkusRequestFilter.lambda$createBlockingHandler$1(QuarkusRequestFilter.java:71)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$null$0(ContextImpl.java:159)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.AbstractContext.dispatch(AbstractContext.java:100)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextImpl.java:157)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$13.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:543)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

[2022-05-18 11:13:04.0467], WARN , org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper executor-thread-0 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
[2022-05-18 11:13:04.0467], ERROR, org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper executor-thread-0 - Can not call getNString() when field's charset isn't UTF-8
[2022-05-18 11:13:04.0469], ERROR, org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler executor-thread-0 - Uncaught server error: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not initialize a collection batch: [org.keycloak.models.jpa.entities.UserEntity.attributes#<7b8ea28f-f3a1-4410-892c-d6055c857950, 1673bb70-a354-4bdc-a937-55f0ee12a15a, 5493996e-8725-4249-a68c-fffda9baada9, 88d7f5a5-93a2-4885-986e-31d36bc30a85>]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._wrapAsIOE(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:509)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:482)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:400)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1514)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1007)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider.writeTo(ResteasyJackson2Provider.java:345)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.messagebody.AsyncBufferedMessageBodyWriter.asyncWriteTo(AsyncBufferedMessageBodyWriter.java:24)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ServerWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(ServerWriterInterceptorContext.java:87)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.asyncProceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:203)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.getStarted(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:166)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ServerWriterInterceptorContext.lambda$getStarted$0(ServerWriterInterceptorContext.java:73)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ServerWriterInterceptorContext.aroundWriteTo(ServerWriterInterceptorContext.java:93)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ServerWriterInterceptorContext.getStarted(ServerWriterInterceptorContext.java:73)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.lambda$writeNomapResponse$3(ServerResponseWriter.java:163)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ContainerResponseContextImpl.filter(ContainerResponseContextImpl.java:404)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.executeFilters(ServerResponseWriter.java:252)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:101)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:74)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:594)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:151)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.handle(VertxRequestHandler.java:82)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.handle(VertxRequestHandler.java:42)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1212)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:163)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextWrapper.next(RoutingContextWrapper.java:201)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.StaticResourcesRecorder$2.handle(StaticResourcesRecorder.java:67)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.StaticResourcesRecorder$2.handle(StaticResourcesRecorder.java:55)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1212)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:163)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextWrapper.next(RoutingContextWrapper.java:201)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$5.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:380)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$5.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:358)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1212)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:163)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextWrapper.next(RoutingContextWrapper.java:201)
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.integration.web.QuarkusRequestFilter.lambda$createBlockingHandler$1(QuarkusRequestFilter.java:71)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$null$0(ContextImpl.java:159)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.AbstractContext.dispatch(AbstractContext.java:100)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextImpl.java:157)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$13.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:543)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not initialize a collection batch: [org.keycloak.models.jpa.entities.UserEntity.attributes#<7b8ea28f-f3a1-4410-892c-d6055c857950, 1673bb70-a354-4bdc-a937-55f0ee12a15a, 5493996e-8725-4249-a68c-fffda9baada9, 88d7f5a5-93a2-4885-986e-31d36bc30a85>]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollectionBatch(Loader.java:2623)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.LegacyBatchingCollectionInitializerBuilder$LegacyBatchingCollectionInitializer.initialize(LegacyBatchingCollectionInitializerBuilder.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:705)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2203)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:595)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:591)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:387)
    at org.keycloak.models.jpa.UserAdapter.getAttributes(UserAdapter.java:254)
    at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.entities.CachedUser.lambda$new$1(CachedUser.java:66)
    at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.DefaultLazyLoader.get(DefaultLazyLoader.java:43)
    at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.entities.CachedUser.getAttributes(CachedUser.java:96)
    at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserAdapter.getFirstAttribute(UserAdapter.java:199)
    at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserAdapter.getUsername(UserAdapter.java:139)
    at org.keycloak.models.utils.ModelToRepresentation.toRepresentation(ModelToRepresentation.java:212)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.UsersResource.lambda$toRepresentation$2(UsersResource.java:459)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:442)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.StreamDecorator.forEach(StreamDecorator.java:153)
    at org.keycloak.utils.ClosingStream.forEach(ClosingStream.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:274)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$StreamBuilderImpl.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:411)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachOrdered(ReferencePipeline.java:502)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.StreamSerializer.serialize(StreamSerializer.java:71)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.StreamSerializer.serialize(StreamSerializer.java:15)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can not call getNString() when field's charset isn't UTF-8
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getNString(ResultSetImpl.java:1060)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getNString(ResultSetImpl.java:1067)
    at io.agroal.pool.wrapper.ResultSetWrapper.getNString(ResultSetWrapper.java:1637)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.NVarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(NVarcharTypeDescriptor.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3214)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.hydrateEntityState(Loader.java:1811)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1784)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1624)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:748)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1047)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:998)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:967)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:327)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollectionBatch(Loader.java:2616)
```

I assume this is due to some mismatch in the *charset/collation* in the database *tables/fields* but the problem is this used to work without an issue in keycloak 9.0.0

I have started keycloak 18 in default database auto-migration mode and the migrated tables appears to be in the same state as the ones used by the previous version (keycloak 9.0.0)

I have set the JDBC properties using the configuration;

`--db-url-properties=characterEncoding=latin1&characterSetResults=UTF-8`

These are essentially the same JDBC configurations used by the previous version as well (obviously configured differently in the standalone-ha.xml). Also I have tried changing the **characterEncoding** above to **UTF-8** but to no avail

Any help is highly appreciated

(from comment)

```
CREATE TABLE USER_ATTRIBUTE | CREATE TABLE USER_ATTRIBUTE` (
    NAME varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    VALUE varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL, 
    USER_ID varchar(36) NOT NULL, 
    ID varchar(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'sybase-needs-something-here', 
    PRIMARY KEY (ID), 
    KEY IDX_USER_ATTRIBUTE (USER_ID), 
    KEY IDX_USER_ATTRIBUTE_NAME (NAME,VALUE), 
    CONSTRAINT FK_5HRM2VLF9QL5FU043KQEPOVBR FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) REFERENCES USER_ENTITY (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me!

I've added `--db-url-properties=characterEncoding=latin1&characterSetResults=UTF-8` as the JDBC properties but for some reason Keycloak v18 (Quarkus) applied only the first param `(characterEncoding=latin1)` and not the second one. It appears that the second one `(characterSetResults=UTF-8)` solves the problem.

I assume it's because the default `characterEncoding` and `characterSetResults` values of MySQL Connector 8.0 has changed compared to the previous 5.7 version

From what I understood, if we don't set this parameter `(characterSetResults=UTF-8)` the default value of the database is used (in my case `latin1`) and because the connector, as the default value, expects `utf8` it throws an SQLException. Can someone enlighten me whether I've understood this correctly :-)

Thanks [@Rick James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1766831/rick-james) for the support

Answer (score 0):

```
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?useUnicode=true&character_set_server=utf8mb4
```

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- If it does not declare the columns to be `utf8` or `utf8mb4`, then there will be characters that cannot be stored in the database.

Comment: I tried changing the `db-url` config to what you have suggested but still the same error is there

Comment: Here's the SHOW CREATE TABLE

`USER_ATTRIBUTE | CREATE TABLE `USER_ATTRIBUTE` (
  `NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `VALUE` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER_ID` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `ID` varchar(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'sybase-needs-something-here',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `IDX_USER_ATTRIBUTE` (`USER_ID`),
  KEY `IDX_USER_ATTRIBUTE_NAME` (`NAME`,`VALUE`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_5HRM2VLF9QL5FU043KQEPOVBR` FOREIGN KEY (`USER_ID`) REFERENCES `USER_ENTITY` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1`

Comment: Are the `CHARACTER SETs` consistent?  I see `latin1` in the table; what is Java doing?  What are the parameters that Hibernate used to connect to MySQL?

Comment: `--db-url-properties=characterEncoding=latin1`
These are the jdbc params I've set. This is the same as previous configs used by Keycloak 9. Database table properties are also the same before migration and after. Just that with new Keycloak 18 (quarkus) this exception is thrown. Any other way I can change the JDBC properties? Could it be an issue with new MySQL connector 8? Previous version used MySQL connector 5.1.7 I think

Comment: @AvishkaPerera - For Java (JDBC):
    ⚈  ?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8 in the getConnection() call.
For Hikari (perhaps):
    ⚈  spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=utf-8
    ⚈  spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.CharSet=utf-8
    ⚈  spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true
(or maybe it is =yes and =utf8)